# I would like to know if the "Acer Nitro 5 AN517-41-R1CH" USB-C type supports the displayport

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, usb-c

Hello I would like to know if the Nitro 5 AN517-41-R1CH USB-C type connector supports the DisplayPort. The logo displayed is only "USB" (https://www.laptopspirit.fr/comparateur/images/fiches/3/G-33566-7-acer-nitro-5-an517-52-rbg-6.jpg) but the documentation tells it's a USB 3.2 Gen 2 Type-C. see there: https://www.acer.com/datasheets/2021/4876/AN517-41/NH.QBGEZ.007.html

Thank you for your answer.

Javaiste

Comment: Does not look like it does, I would contact Acer support to find out for sure.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual, it does not look like the USB-C port has DisplayPort pass-through.  Sad, because it is a great laptop otherwise.  I purchased one online but after finding out that it didn't support DisplayPort, I cancelled the order.

Note that you can still use a docking station that supports DisplayLink (e.g. Dell D6000) which creates a virtual graphics card within Windows and uses the CPU to compress the data and send it out over the USB-C port.

[image]